# Inserting data From Zend's form to database

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a problem with inserting Records into a DB using Zend FrameWork 2.
There are no records saved into the DB when submitting the Form and also no Error Messages Appear,  just the Confirmation Message telling me that it `<< Registered Successfully >>`
Here is my code, thanks in advance:

```
 // App/config/autoload/global.php
 return array(
       'db'   => array(
            'driver'         => 'pdo',
            'dsn'            =>  'mysql:dbname=zf_app;host=localhost;port:8080',
            'username'       => 'zf_user',
            'password'       => 'zf_pass',
            'driver_options' => array(
                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                            ),

                    ),
      'service_manager'   => array(
            'factories'   => array(
                        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' =>'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
                        ),
            ),
 );

   #################################################################

 //App\module\Users\src\Users\Model\Usertable.php

   <?php

namespace Users\Model;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class UserTable
{
protected $tableGateway ;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}

public function saveUser(User $user)
{
    $data = array(
            'email'     => $user->email ,
            'name'      => $user->name,
            'password'  => $user->password,
        );

    $id = (int)$user->id ;
    if($id == 0)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    } else {
        if($this->getUser($id))
        {
            $this->tableGateway->update($data , array('id' => $id));
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("User ID does not Exist ");

        }
    }
}

public function getUser($id)
{
    $id      = (int)$id;
    $rowset  = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id ));
    $row     = $rowset->current();

    if(!$row)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Could not Find row $id ");
    }
    return $row ;
  }

}



   ##########################################################
  // App\module\Users\src\Users\Controller\RegisterController.php

     <?php

 namespace Users\Controller;
 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
 use Users\Form\RegisterForm;
 use Users\Form\RegisterFilter;
 use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;


class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
      $form      = new RegisterForm();
      $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
      return $viewModel;
  }


  public function confirmAction()
  {
      $viewModel = new ViewModel();
      return $viewModel;
  }


  public function processAction()
  {
      if(!$this->request->isPost())
      {
          return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array(
                                                      'controller'   => 'register',
                                                    'action'       => 'index',
                                                      ));
      }

      $post = $this->request->getPost();
      $form = new RegisterForm();
      $inputFilter = new RegisterFilter();
      $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
      $form->setData($post);

      if (!$form->isValid())
      {
          $model = new ViewModel(array('error' => true , 'form' => $form));
          $model->setTemplate('users/register/index');
          return $model;
      }

      return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array('controller' => 'register'  , 'action' => 'confirm' ,));

  }


  public function createUser(array $data)
  {
      $sm                  = $this->getServiceLocator();
      $dbAdapter           = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
      $resultSetPrototype  = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();

      $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User);
      $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user' ,  $dbAdapter , null , $resultSetPrototype);

       $user   = new User();
       $user->exchangeArray($data);
       $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);
       $userTable->saveUser($user);
       $this->createUser($form->getData());
       return true;
     }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create  // App/config/autoload/local.php

// App/config/autoload/local.php

return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => "zf_user",
        'password' => "zf_pass",
    )
);
```

and remove username and password from global.php

Comment: First of all , thank you for your answer , unfortunately i tried to do that but it doesn't work also

Answer (score 0):

What is the User in public function saveUser(User $user) ? You didn't use User file.

Comment: instead of 'public function saveUser()'  i use 'public function createUser(array $data)'
i takes data as array and then pass them to db 
.... and inside it i'm using user file 
i'll Add the Code To my post if you want to check it

Comment: I think that you must use ZfcUser\Entity\User in App\module\Users\src\Users\Model\Usertable.php